# can I change the UINavigation bar's height on iOS8 using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to change the height of the `UINavigationBar` which I embedded my view controller in.

I have tried set the frame using my own class `MyNavigationController:UINavigationController` but it won't work.

Plz help me!

Comment: posting on some of your work could be helpful

Comment: I would wonder why you're doing this. And if you want to do this properly, you wouldn't do it on UINavigationController. You'd make your own class of UINavigationBar (not subclass) which sets the top navigation bar height. But then of course you'd have to reimplement all of UINavigationController as well.